# Yii relations subquery

Tags: php, mysql, yii, subquery

This is the query I have:

```
select * from order_shipping_date osd inner join  
(SELECT MAX(osd.id) as id FROM  order_shipping_date osd 
group by osd.order_id) osdi ON osd.id = osdi.id
```

I'm fine with keeping it so, but would like to make it possible to define it as [relations](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.18/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L540)

This is more comfy to use such code later
Is this doable at all? I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 1):

[Additional options](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-options) can be specified in relationship declaration.

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'orderShippingDate' => array(
            // define you relation
            'join' => '(/* subquery here*/) osdi ON osdi.id=orderShippingDate.id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER JOIN'
        ),
    );
}
```